# How to include a music file with a .jar file?

Tags: java, embedded-resource, javasound

I am having trouble with my netbeans. I have made a program that only plays a background music. When I run the program from netbeans IDE it runs with the music without any error. But when I am trying to run the .jar file the program runs correctly just without the music. I have checked the path hundred times, but its not working. No error, no nothings just, the music is not playing from the .jar file. 
Why so?

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) { 
  new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
     try { 
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
        AudioInputStream inputStream; 
        inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            this.getClass().getResource(url)); 
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
     } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
     } 
    } 
   }).start(); }
```

Comment: You may need to tell us more, in particular, how are you trying to access the resource? As a File? If so, know that Files don't exist in Jar files, but instead you need to access it as a resource.

Comment: @JakubZaverka
in the class file
`public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream;
                    inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(url));
                    clip.open(inputStream);`

Comment: @JakubZaverka
`clip.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }`

Comment: Tushar: You will note that this site's software does not allow formatting of code in comments. So better to edit your original question and post the formatted code there. That is if Paul's good answer doesn't help you solve the problem. 1+ to Paul Sanwald.

Comment: So you are using Streams it appears. Next you need to check that the path you are using to the resource is relative to the class path -- the base location of your class files in the jar.

Comment: How to do it? I have pasted the sound file in every folder. Still its not happening

Comment: 1) In what path in the Jar is the music path/name? Show the output (as an edit) of `jar -tvf the.jar` 2) What is the value passed to `final String url`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Change `} catch (Exception e) {` to `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); `

Answer (score 6):

you should be using [getResourceAsStream(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to access files like this, you'll need to ensure that they are present on the classpath.

Without any code to look at, I am guessing you are trying to use a FileInputStream, or similar, which is not going to work, as a jar file doesn't have a concept of a traditional filesystem.

Comment: Not to mention that he needs to pack the music file also in the jar (which most probably, by default, netbeans won't be doing it when creating the jar)

Comment: The music file doesn't need to be packed into the jar, it just needs to be in the classpath.

Comment: how can i put the file in class path?

Comment: you just need to make sure the file is in the classpath of your jar. the easiest way to do this is make sure it's on the same level and location of your compiled classes in your jar. but you can specify this in your META-INF also

Comment: @Tushar classpath and packagepath are completely different. Classpath is a path where your .class files directory. If you put your file in packagepath like .java then .jar wont recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the .jar ... and you want your music to play when you run the .jar ... then you really ought to put your music file *IN THE JAR*.  As Paul Sanwald already told you, ["getResourceAsStream()"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)  is the API you want to use.

It will work also in your IDE.

I happen to prefer the Eclipse IDE, and in Eclipse you'd copy your file to the "src" folder in your project (in which case it'll automatically get put in the right place when you export your .jar)

This link explains how to do it in NetBeans:

- http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSpecialJar

Comment: can you please edit my code? I cant understand where to add it. 
is it like `inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(url));` this type?